# Search Items using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a search using jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var opts = $('#content li').map(function() {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });

    $('#someinput').keyup(function(){
        var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput').val(), 'i');
        var content = $('#content').empty();
        opts.each(function() {
            if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                content.append($('</li>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="someinput" placeholder="Search" name="search" >

<section id="content">
    <ul id="newSonglist">
        <!-- items here -->
    </ul>
</section>
```

Items look like this:

```
<li onclick="myControl.selectList(this,1)">
    <a class="frmPlay" href="">
        <img class="frmPlay" src="images/Right.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <span style="display:none;" class="musicData" pic="" title="Chris" brown="" grass="" aint="" greener="" value=""></span>
    <div class="r">
        <img class="picStyle" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="textBox">
        Chris Brown Grass Aint Greener
        <p>Sent by Nikan</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I search `Chris Brown` it will remove all of the contents and it does not exclude the `Chris Brown`. Can you guys help me make it work? Thanks.

Comment: hi if u append it wont exclude the old values in Jquery

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please have a read though the [help]. Id' suggest your question is well formatted, etc. but seems to be lacking an answerable question? This isn't really somewhere for debugging help.

Comment: @gayathri oh so how should i do it ?

Comment: @Liam well i could not solve it so i thought i can ask

Comment: if possible create a fiddle  with sample data or plunker so that will be easy to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine except for your new `li` creation. You are creating the `li` element using `$('</li>')` instead of `$('<li>')` (Note the `/`)

```
// You wrote </li> instead of <li>
content.append($('<li>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgr5eskL/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure if I got what you trying to do, however for a simple JavaScript search UI, I'd rather do something more in the following fashion:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#someinput").on("keyup", function() {
    var search_string = $(this).val()
    var criteria = new RegExp(search_string, "i");
    $("#content li").each(function() {
      var li_element = $(this);
      var filtered_out = li_element.text().match(criteria) == null && search_string.length > 0 
      if (filtered_out) {
        li_element.hide();
      } else {
        li_element.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="someinput" placeholder="Search" name="search">

<section id="content">
  <ul id="newSonglist">
    <!-- items here -->
  </ul>


  <li>
    <a class="frmPlay" href="">
      <img class="frmPlay" src="images/Right.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <span style="display:none;" class="musicData" pic="" title="Chris" brown="" grass="" aint="" greener="" value=""></span>
    <div class="r">
      <img class="picStyle" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="textBox">
      Chris Brown Grass Aint Greener
      <p>Sent by Nikan</p>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a class="frmPlay" href="">
      <img class="frmPlay" src="images/Right.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <span style="display:none;" class="musicData" pic="" title="Chris" brown="" grass="" aint="" greener="" value=""></span>
    <div class="r">
      <img class="picStyle" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="textBox">
      Jack Johnson
      <p>Sent by Nikan</p>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a class="frmPlay" href="">
      <img class="frmPlay" src="images/Right.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <span style="display:none;" class="musicData" pic="" title="Chris" brown="" grass="" aint="" greener="" value=""></span>
    <div class="r">
      <img class="picStyle" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="textBox">
      Aguillera
      <p>Sent by Nikan</p>
    </div>
  </li>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Suggestion  :)

Comment: Wow i just tried it out and its perfect , i would add this as best answer but i already did selected above answer